# Jquery: Ajax-loader not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an Ajax-loader work, but it's not firing. Here is what I do:

HTML:

```
<div class="ajax-loader">
  <img src="ajax-loader.gif">
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
function myFunction() {
    $('.ajax-loader').css("visibility", "visible");

    //Function doing it's work

    $('.ajax-loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
}
```

CSS:

```
.ajax-loader {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

When I enter $('.ajax-loader').css("visibility", "visible"); in the console my loader loads, it's just not working when I put it at the beginning of the function. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,

EDIT: My page kind of freeze when the function is fired, maybe it's because of that. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Are you using some plugin named ajax loader?

Comment: no, it's the class name.

Comment: Could you post the element that is used to trigger the function?

Comment: Are you using $.ajax function somewhere?

Comment: The element that fires the function : <button onclick="myFunction()" class="myBtn1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#build">1 - Create campaign</button>

Comment: No Ajax function in my code.

Comment: what's the problem? the loader is not showing up or is not hidding correctly?

Comment: It's not showing up at all.

Comment: I just edited my question with what possibly is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
function loader_hide() {
    $('.ajax-loader').hide();
}
function loader_show() {
    $('.ajax-loader').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="button" value="show" onclick="loader_show();"/>
<input type="button" value="hide" onclick="loader_hide();"/>
 <div class="ajax-loader">
  <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/91700/screenshots/3038974/loader.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: The loader should stop when the function finishes it's work, and not on button click. Thank you.

Comment: Call `loader_show();` before ajax-request. And the function `loader_hide();` after the data is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by creating a function load() that load the loader and call it onclick, then I used a set setTimeout of 10ms, giving the time to the gif to load.

```
function load() {
    $('.ajax-loader').css("visibility", "visible");
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="load();setTimeout(myFunction, 10)" class="myBtn1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#build">1 - Create campaign</button>
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Having to add a timeout for no real reason sounds like a "document ready" issue.

Comment: The reason is that my dom freeze when onclick, so I had to give time to the loader to load.. If you have a better solution I'll gladly take it.